# Authentication request failed: Bad credentials [LDAP: error code 49 - data 52e, v1db1]

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, authentication, ldap

I am trying to authenticate with BindAuthenticator but it is giving me Authentication errors.

```
18:14:32,764 org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter DEBUG http-bio-8080-exec-12 authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter:189 - Request is to process authentication
18:14:32,765 org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager DEBUG http-bio-8080-exec-12 authentication.ProviderManager:152 - Authentication attempt using org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.LdapAuthenticationProvider
18:14:32,767 org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.AbstractLdapAuthenticationProvider DEBUG http-bio-8080-exec-12 authentication.LdapAuthenticationProvider:65 - Processing authentication request for user: admin.manager@XDEV.com
18:14:32,770 org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.BindAuthenticator DEBUG http-bio-8080-exec-12 authentication.BindAuthenticator:108 - Attempting to bind as uid=admin.manager@XDEV.com,o=X-DEV,dc=Xexternal,dc=com
18:14:32,770 org.springframework.security.ldap.DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource$1 DEBUG http-bio-8080-exec-12 ldap.DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource:76 - Removing pooling flag for user uid=admin.manager@XDEV.com,o=LS360-DEV,dc=Xexternal,dc=com
18:14:33,427 org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.BindAuthenticator DEBUG http-bio-8080-exec-12 authentication.BindAuthenticator:152 - Failed to bind as uid=admin.manager@XDEV.com: org.springframework.ldap.AuthenticationException: [LDAP: error code 49 - 80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C0903A9, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 52e, v1db1
```

XML configuration:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

    <security:global-method-security
        secured-annotations="enabled" />

    <security:http pattern="/theme/**" security="none" />
    <security:http pattern="/javascript/**" security="none" />
    <security:http pattern="/favicon.ico" security="none" />
    <security:http pattern="/login" security="none" />

    <beans:bean id="contextSource"
        class="org.springframework.security.ldap.DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource">
        <beans:constructor-arg value="ldap://10.0.X.X:389/DC=Xexternal,DC=com" />
        <beans:property name="base" value="O=X-DEV,DC=Xexternal,DC=com" />
        <beans:property name="userDn" value="CN=X-dev,O=X-DEV,DC=Xexternal,DC=com" />
        <beans:property name="password" value="X!" />
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="userSearch"
        class="org.springframework.security.ldap.search.FilterBasedLdapUserSearch">
        <beans:constructor-arg index="0" value="" />
        <beans:constructor-arg index="1" value="uid={0}" />
        <beans:constructor-arg index="2" ref="contextSource" />
        <beans:property name="searchSubtree" value="true" />
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="passwordEncoder"
        class="org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.ShaPasswordEncoder">
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="ldapAuthProvider"
        class="org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.LdapAuthenticationProvider">
        <beans:constructor-arg>
            <beans:bean
                class="org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.BindAuthenticator">
                <beans:constructor-arg ref="contextSource"/>
                <beans:property name="userDnPatterns">
                    <beans:list>
                        <beans:value>uid={0}</beans:value>
                    </beans:list>
                </beans:property>
                <beans:property name="userSearch" ref="userSearch" />
                <!-- <beans:property name="passwordEncoder" ref="passwordEncoder" /> -->
            </beans:bean>
        </beans:constructor-arg>
        <beans:constructor-arg>
            <beans:bean
                class="org.springframework.security.ldap.userdetails.DefaultLdapAuthoritiesPopulator">
                <beans:constructor-arg ref="contextSource" />
                <beans:constructor-arg value="O=X-DEV" />
            </beans:bean>
        </beans:constructor-arg>
    </beans:bean>

    <!-- LDAP server details -->
    <security:authentication-manager>
        <security:authentication-provider
            ref="ldapAuthProvider">
        </security:authentication-provider>
    </security:authentication-manager>


    <security:http>
        <security:form-login login-page="/login"
            login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check" default-target-url="/search"
            authentication-failure-url="/login?login_error=true" />
        <security:http-basic />
        <security:logout logout-url="/login" />
        <security:session-management
            invalid-session-url="/login" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/**"
            access='ROLE_USER,IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY, IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED' />
    </security:http>



</beans:beans>
```

Comment: Did you try connecting with JXPlorer (http://jxplorer.org/)? Error code 52e is typically bound with invalid credentials... Do you have two users admin.manager in the same LDAP but in different trees?

Comment: I am using ldapadmin.org. I searched for the user for multiple entries but only one was found.

Comment: To which LDAP are you connecting to? Microsoft Active Directory?

Comment: have you tried to replace generic LdapAuthenticationProvider with ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider? Not sure if it could help, but this link might be helpful: http://www.iceycake.com/2012/06/microsoft-active-directory-ms-ad-authentication-with-java-spring-security-3-1-0/

Comment: more or less same error

Answer (score 0):

I made following changes to make this whole thing work.

```
<beans:bean id="userSearch"
        class="org.springframework.security.ldap.search.FilterBasedLdapUserSearch">
        <beans:constructor-arg index="0" value="" />
        <beans:constructor-arg index="1" value="**(userPrincipalName={0})**" />
        <beans:constructor-arg index="2" ref="contextSource" />
        <beans:property name="searchSubtree" value="true" />
    </beans:bean>
```

plus I added ROLE_ADMIN in authorization.

```
<security:http>
    <security:form-login login-page="/login"
        login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check" default-target-url="/searchcourse"
        authentication-failure-url="/login?login_error=true" />
    <security:http-basic />
    <security:logout logout-url="/login" />
    <security:session-management
        invalid-session-url="/login" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**"
        access='**ROLE_ADMIN,** ROLE_USER,IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY, IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED' />
</security:http>
```

I read somewhere on stackoverflow that it is a must to have ROLE_ADMIN.

I hope above this helps someone else as well.

thanks,